# Script after opening jar file doesn't execute code after and not throwing any error

Tags: python, subprocess, pyautogui

Script should open java file and fill inputs, so it opens file but it doesn't execute code that goes after and not showing any error in console. But if i open file manually and run code without opening file then everything is working

```
from pywinauto import application
import pyautogui
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\file.jar'],shell=True)

time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.typewrite("login")
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.moveTo(611,601)
pyautogui.click()
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click()
time.sleep(40)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.call` waits for the subprocess to finish. You have to use `subprocess.Popen` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Subprocess `call` does not work with a list of arguments and `shell=True` at the same time. Either you say `shell=False` or you join the list to a string.

For example you could say:

```
subprocess.call(" ".join(['java', '-jar', 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\file.jar']), shell=True)
```